# Passed value is not preserved

Tags: asp.net-core, parameter-passing, razor-pages

Not MVC!

Hi all,

What am I doing wrong here...

Im trying to pass an integer value from the onPost method of a Razor Page(Scores/Create.cshtml) to the onGet method of another page(/Scores/Index.cshtml) however the value is not being preserved and I either get null or 0 when inspecting the id value in the onGet method depending on how I send the integer.

I know this works using routes as I do this on another page

```
<a asp-page="/Scores/Index" asp-route-id="@item.ElementId">Update scores</a>
```

I have tried passing the value from an entity property like in the code example below, from ViewData variable, also from a locally created integer and finally just passing an integer value itself. In all cases the value is correct in the OnPost but never gets to the onGet.

The OnPost

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        _context.TScores.Add(TScores);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToPage("./Index","OnGet",TScores.ElementId);
    }
```

The OnGet

```
    public async Task OnGetAsync(int? id)
    {  
            TElements telement = new TElements();

            telement =  _context.TElements.Where(a => a.ElementId == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

I have also tried it without setting the OnGet method name in the RedirecttoPage

I am expecting to get the value of id in the onGet to match TScores.ElementID passed from the onPost.

Thanks in advance

D

Answer (score 1):

The parameter requires an object, specifically an anonymous object of route values; it doesn't know what to do with an int.

```
return RedirectToPage("./Index", new { id = TScores.ElementId });
```